# Problem with getting Circle round when increasing radius with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

When creating a Circle object with JavaFX and is using Graphic Context to stroke the Oval I want it to expand outside of the first created oval. So it will be larger than the last one and go around the first if that makes sense to you.

**Here is a picture of what it is now:**

[image]

**Here is a picture of what I would like it to do. As well as the fillOval method too:**

[image: Expected]

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 200);
GraphicsContext gc;
gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setLineWidth(1);

Circle c = new Circle();

canvas.setOnMousePressed(e ->
{
        c.setCenterX(e.getX());
        c.setCenterY(e.getY());
});

canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e ->
{
        c.setRadius((Math.abs(e.getX() - c.getCenterX()) + Math.abs(e.getY() - c.getCenterY())) / 2);
        gc.strokeOval(c.getCenterX(), c.getCenterY(), c.getRadius(), c.getRadius());
    }
});
```

For some reason it begins at the left corner. I cant understand why it does that. It doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me your assumption on how strokeOval is defined is wrong.

```
public void strokeOval​(double x, double y, double w, double h)
```

The parameters define a bounding rectangle and not, as you assume, a center and a radius. Just have a look at the documentation for more details.

Comment: I got it to work by changing inside the `strokeOval(c.getCenterX() - c.getRadius(), c.getCenterY() - c.getRadius(), c.getRadius() * 2, c.getRadius() * 2);`